# Markdown - Begin bullet list with a sublist item

Tags: markdown

I have an odd situation which I understand to be exeptional. What I want to do is to begin a Markdown formatted List with a sublist item.

I know that usually a bullet list is composed like this:

```
* List item 1
 * Sublist item 1.1
* List item 2
 * Sublist item 2.1
 * Sublist item 2.2
* List item 3
... etc.
```

Now I would like the list to begin with a sublist item. Is this possible? My attempts to enforce it with the code below did not achieve anything.

```
 * Sublist item 1.1
* List item 2
... etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may nest the sublist on the first line of the parent list item:

```
* * Sublist item 1.1
* List item 2
  * Sublist item 2.1
  * Sublist item 2.2
* List item 3
```

Which results in:

> - - Sublist item 1.1
> - List item 2
>
>   - Sublist item 2.1
>   - Sublist item 2.2
> - List item 3

While the above works on most implementations, it is an edge case any may not work in all. Therefore, YMMV.

Note that both this answer and @the4kman's answer include a parent bullet. That is unavoidable. The only way a list item can be a "sublist item" is if it is inside a parent list item. As a reminder, Markdown is a subset of HTML and it would not be possible to have a sublist item without a parent in HTML either. Presumably you could use CSS to hide the bullet in the resulting HTML, but that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution (it displays an empty list item before the first sublist), but that's the best I could get without modifying CSS.

Create a line before the first sublist item and enter [a non-breaking space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) after it:

```
* &nbsp;
 * Sublist item 1.1
* List item 2
 * Sublist item 2.1
 * Sublist item 2.2
* List item 3
```

**Result:**

- - Sublist item 1.1
- List item 2

  - Sublist item 2.1
  - Sublist item 2.2
- List item 3